# Occasional problem with Cascading Combi Boxes in MS Access (Module not found)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a database with a cascading combo box in three forms (all the same cascading combo box using the same data set for the options). However, it actually works, but still gives the following error from time to time (translated from Germ. to English):

**You entered the expression After Update as the event property setting. This expression caused an error: Module not found.
The expression may not return the name of a macro, user-defined function name, or [event procedure].
An error may have occurred while evaluating a function of a result or a marker.**

I used the following code to update the cascading boxes:

```
Private Sub Level_1_AfterUpdate()
Me.Level_2.Requery
End Sub
Private Sub Level_2_AfterUpdate()
Me.Level_3.Requery
End Sub
```

and the same for all the other levels (four levels in total).

Does anyone know, why I get this issue and how I can solve it? Does it have to do with the updating? For the option of the combo box I created a data set and it is used by all three forms.

Comment: Does it happen with all forms? What data is selected? Suggest you post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Yes, happens with all forms. However, weirdly it works again, when opening another form, when one form gave an error... :/ Might that imply that I should use a seperate data sheet for the drop down options for every form, not the same due to some query problem? I'll try to find a forum for that, thank you!

Comment: Multiple comboboxes can use same dataset (data sheet?). What do you mean by dataset (or data sheet) - a table or query?

Comment: I was actually wrong, I confused it with a previous attempt of mind. Every possible option in the combo boxes for every form uses a different table for query, but the content is the same. You are the person from the other forum I found :D Thanks for your help!! I uploaded the file via .zip now :)

Comment: Review of db leads to conclusion there is corruption and solution is to rebuild, starting with comboboxes until issue goes away.